# SQL Server sp_getapplock AND sp_releaseapplock throws Exception when release lock

Tags: sql-server, locking

I was using SQL Server's lock functions likes below

```
sp_getapplock
sp_releaseapplock
```

I have specified `@LockOwner = 'Session'`

But throw belows exception every time:

> *com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot release the application lock (Database Principal: 'dbo', Resource: '89999') because it is not currently held*

Any suggestions or ideas are welcome!

REGARDS!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [SETLOCK]
    @...
AS
DECLARE
@RESULT INT;
BEGIN TRANSACTION
EXEC @RESULT = sp_getapplock @...
                 @LockOwner = 'Session';

IF @RESULT = -3
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is pretty clear: you did not acquired the applock on resource `89999`. You must specify `Session` (as the value for `@LockOwner` parameter) also in the call to [`sp_releaselock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238897(v=sql.80).aspx) and **the lock release  must occur on the same session as the lock acquisition**. Another possible cause is imbalanced acquire/release calls (you have an extra release).

As a side note there is no need for a transaction when using Session scoped locks.

Comment: Hi Remus, the lock release must occur on the same session... I'm sorry but ask few more: how to judges the same session? Does it if use same connection object in code is OK? I have passed the same connection object to the method when using lock or release but occured this error? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Same session ~= same @@SPID. It must be the same connection which must not be closed/re-open.

Comment: @RemusRusanu there is no such parameter as `Session`.

Comment: @ArtemNovikov [`@LockOwner`: The value can be **Transaction** (the default) or **Session**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If that helps you can try @LockOwner = 'Transaction'.